# kill sessions for other machines

Tags: kill, session

I've an admin and client site. Multiple users will view at client site at the same time. It is possible that I can force the users logout of my client site from admin site? I'm now using classic ASP and the In Proc session is used. Is there a way where I can kill all the sessions of the users and force them to logout?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to reset IIS server that the client site is hosted on, i believe you can do this by stopping & starting the site from IIS Manager.

Comment: for example, there are 2 users, named A and B..Both A and B sign in to the same website..and A restarted his own IIS..B will not be forced to logout